# How to create random circles on flutter? circles should not be overlapping with each other

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I would like to create something similar to below given photo in the flutter. This is the output I need in flutter. Circles should not be overlapping with each other. Below given code just gives one circle but i need multiple with random placements.

REFERENCE OUTPUT
[image]

```
  Container(
            width: 28,
            height: 28,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.green.withOpacity(0.25), // border color
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(2), // border width
              child: Container( // or ClipRRect if you need to clip the content
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: Colors.blue, // inner circle color
                ),
                child: Container(), // inner content
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: seems like  your attached image is missing

Comment: hi, 
Did you find a way to achieve this kind of design.

Comment: have you found anything? I'm looking for similar.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to generate circles with centers placed at random locations, and random radiuses; for each added circle, you would have to check if it overlaps with existing circles, by calculating the cartesian distance among the centers: if that distance is greater than the sum of the radiuses of the two circles being compared, then those two didn't overlap.

Comment: can you provide the basic implementation code?